# Unit DI to Microsoft DI - Conditional Resolving

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm converting my .Net Framework code to .Net Core 3.1.

In my old code I used Unity to handle my DI, now I'm using Microsoft's DI tools.

However, I'm having trouble mimicking how I injected a particular strategy pattern implementation like I did in Unity:

```
 container.RegisterType<IService, ConcreteServiceA>("MyString");

 container.RegisterType<IStrategy, Strategy>(
       new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedArrayParameter<IService>(
                new ResolvedParameter<IService>("MyString")
            )
       ));
```

How can I do the equivalent using Microsoft DI?  Thank you.

Comment: Unity does have an [extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) that can plug into Microsoft DI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to do, note the following

> ### Default service container replacement
>
> The built-in service container is designed to serve the needs of the framework and most consumer apps. We recommend using the built-in container unless you need a specific feature that the built-in container doesn't support, such as:
>
> - Property injection
> - **Injection based on name** *(emphasis mine)*
> - Child containers
> - Custom lifetime management
> - `Func<T>` support for lazy initialization
> - Convention-based registration

Reference [Default service container replacement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement)

Unity does have an [extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) that can plug into Microsoft DI

Install the nuget package

```
Install-Package Unity.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
```

And use the relevant extensions.

For example

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUnityServiceProvider()   //<---- Add this line
        .ConfigureContainer<IUnityContainer>( container => {
            container.RegisterType<IService, ConcreteServiceA>("MyString");

            container.RegisterType<IStrategy, Strategy>(
               new InjectionConstructor(
                   new ResolvedArrayParameter<IService>(
                       new ResolvedParameter<IService>("MyString")
                    )
               ));
        })
        //...
```

Comment: Good to know... I may go down that route.  I'd like to use the Microsoft DI library if possible but I can make the switch if I can't figure this out.

Comment: @mint the default DI container is very limited in functionality. As you have already experienced trying to replicated Unity features. MS made the container easily extendable for that same reason. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement